# HTML table rowspan

Tags: html

I have a table like below (on the left) - how to make it to be like the one on the right ?

[image]

```
    <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
              <td colspan='3' rowspan='2'>Lorem</td>
              <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>2</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>A</td>
              <td>B</td>
              <td>C</td>
          </tr>
       </thead>
    </table>
```

Comment: remove `<td>1</td>` and `<td>2</td>` [**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/socokusi/1/edit) ??

Comment: HTML is not actually programming. It is markup and does not belong on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td colspan='3'>Lorem</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here your code!!

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/all.css"/>
    <title>STACKOVERFLOW</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">Lorem</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
table {border-collapse: collapse}
table td {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
              <td colspan='3'>Lorem</td>

          </tr>

          <tr>
              <td>A</td>
              <td>B</td>
              <td>C</td>
          </tr>
       </thead>
    </table>
```